# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasTime') in fullcalendar when pulling through large number of SQL records

Tags: javascript, php, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

As the title says, I am getting that uncaught TypeError when I pull through for example 1800 records on the SQL statement to populate the calendar. If I add a LIMIT clause to the statement (to around 1500) records, it will pull through ok and display.

I could use this as a solution as a last resort basis, but ideally I would like to pull through all of the records. I did some research and found this question [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasTime') in fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69133397/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-hastime-in-f) which I believe is on the right lines, however I'm not too sure how to add my events as a javascript response variable, as I am currently accessing events using a URL which json encodes the data. Any help would be appreciated. See below for my calendar initialisation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
editable:true,  
header:{
  left:'prev,next today',
  center:'title',
  right:'month,agendaWeek',
},
droppable: true, 
events: 'deliveryCalendars/deliverySheduleLoad.php',
```

Then my code to put the data into an array

```
$deliveryDateArray[] = array(
    'mainID'  => $row["orderID"],
    'id'   => $row["DeliveryID"],
    'title'   => $row["lastName"],
    'start'   => $row["deliveryDate"],
    'color' => $color,
    'materials' => $insulation
);
echo json_encode($deliveryDateArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Show the response from the server when you get that error.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. the response from the server is "fullcalendar.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasTime')" but as I said will only happen after a certain number of records are returned from the SQL query.

Comment: That's not the response from the server, that's an error generated by fullCalendar's Javascript code when it cannot parse the event data properly. Are any of your events missing their start date/time? Or are any of the date/time strings formatted incorrectly? Examine the JSON closely. You can see the raw JSON being generated by either a) looking in your browser's Network tab when the calendar is loading, and then clicking on the call to the deliverySheduleLoad.php script and looking at the Response tab, or b) by going directly to the deliverySheduleLoad.php URL in a separate browser tab.

Comment: Either that, or the sheer number of events is causing some sort of error either in generating the JSON or in the query, causing it to return an unexpected result in some way - e.g. an error embedded in the JSON, or a complete failure. Again that's another reason to examine the raw response carefully.

Comment: But...why are you trying to put >1000 events on a single calendar at a time? If they're all visible then that's going to be completely crowded and unreadable for anyone. Humans cannot process that quantity of information at one time, it is going to be no use for anyone trying to view it. Even >100 events would be a bit much.

Comment: And if they're _not_ all going to be visible at once, e.g. because they occur across many different months, then why are you downloading them all at once? Fullcalendar automatically supplies start/end dates in the AJAX request it sends, enabling you to filter the response data to just the events which occur within the time period the calendar is going to display. Then if (and only if) the user changes the date range on the calendar, fullCalendar will make another request to the server to retrieve new data for that period. Much more efficient than dumping everything up-front, just in case.

Comment: @ADyson - Yeah I've checked the JSON, and everything is in the correct format. I've done extensive testing on the script, and for example, if I was to add $deliveryDateArray and $deliveryDateArray2, populating from two different SQL statements, one ordering by ascending, the other by descending, but keeping the limit at 1000, it will populate the records ok.

Comment: @ADyson - The reason I need all 1000 events to be showing is because the client has quite a long lead time in terms of orders, so sometimes the dates could be set 1-2 years out. How would I go about passing the date range selected (ie only january, which then becomes a february variable if the month is changed) into my deliveryScheduleLoad.php page. Once I get it in there yeah I think that would be a good way to work it, just not too sure how to get the date selected from calendar to AJAX page.

Comment: `How would I go about passing the date range selected (ie only january, which then becomes a february variable if the month is changed) into my deliveryScheduleLoad.php page`...like I said, fullCalendar already does this for you automatically, as per the documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed. It arrives as two GET parameters (`start` and `end`) which you can then use to filter your SQL query accordingly.

Comment: @ADyson ahh that's right actually, I forgot that's the format it arrives to the events url. Perfect, thanks for your help. So am I right in saying then that if I just add a between clause in my SQL statement, and use the start/end variables, those will always be the start and end of the month selected?

Comment: They'll be the start and end date of the current date range visible on the calendar. So if you're in week view and request some dates for which events haven't been downloaded yet, then it'll be a week's range which you receive in the request, if it's a month then you'll get the first and last date currently visible on the month view (which might include day or two before/after - if you look at the grid, you'll see sometimes there are days of the previous/next month visible in order to maintain the square shape of it.). But basically, yes it will.

Comment: @ADyson - perfect thanks for the help